# iOS a:visited link showing default purple color

Tags: ios, css

On my site, I have a few footer links that are showing the wrong border color for iOS devices when the link is visited. This is happening on Chrome and Safari for iOS.

**Desktop**

[image]

**iOS**

[image]

I searched through my code and I am not setting this style anywhere.
I have tried reproducing this in a fiddle/codepen, but since they don't let you redirect, I can't see what the `a:visited` looks like for mobile.

**Code**

```css
.productsalessection {
  width: 34%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
}

.productsalesbox {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 14px 12px;
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
}

.productsalesbadge {
  width: 80px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 6px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.productsalesheading {
  margin-top: 3px;
  color: #444;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.productsalestext {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
  color: #777;
}
```

```html
<a class="w-clearfix productsalessection" target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">
  <div class="w-clearfix productsalesbox">
    <div class="productsalesbadge"><img src="http://www.chicmarket.com/images/SJ.svg">
    </div>
    <div class="productsalesheading">Trusted</div>
    <div class="productsalestext">We proudly maintain a strong relationship with our customers.</div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Changing the color of the `a:visited` works.

```
a:visited {
  color: #C8C8C8;
}
```

But this solution is not ideal because this will mess with other a tags on my site.

I have also tried.

```
a:visited {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}
```

But instead of making the color transparent, it just makes the border black.

I don't normally post links to external sites, but if you would like to take a look and see the problem for yourself, you can check it out [here](http://www.chicmarket.com/product/1489541/13).

Is there a simple fix for this that doesn't require me to set the `a:visited` color for each a tag that I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was only happening to borders of divs inside of `<a>` tags on mobile. In order to fix this I had to not only set `color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);` for `a:visited`, but I had to select the specific div that had the border.

```
a:visited .productsalesbadge {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}
```

This completely removed the purple visited border I was seeing on mobile.